# Subject =LARGE to a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a dashboard that will find the largest ten values based on data in column D and display the contents of column C while excluding from the selection any row that contains a specific value in column B.

I am currently using `=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MATCH(LARGE($D$1:$D$100,1),$D$1:$D$100,0))` to find the largest value in D and display C.

I can't figure out how to exclude from the `LARGE` call any rows that have `SKIPME` in column B.

Comment: I assume you meant to say: ... that will find the 10 **largest** values

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IF` statement to do that:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MATCH(LARGE(IF($B$1:$B$100<>"SKIPME",$D$1:$D$100),1),$D$1:$D$100,0))
```

Except that it also converts the formula into an array equation, so that you now have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work.

You can also use this equivalent function, also called with CSE but slightly shorter:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MATCH(LARGE(($B$1:$B$100<>"SKIPME")*$D$1:$D$100,1),$D$1:$D$100,0))
```

Or if you're only looking for the biggest value, then `MAX` works just as well:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MATCH(MAX(($B$1:$B$100<>"SKIPME")*$D$1:$D$100),$D$1:$D$100,0))
```

Comment: Or maybe even a slightly different approach with `=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MATCH(1,--(D1:D100=MAX(D1:D100*(B1:B100<>"skipme"))),0))`?

Comment: Can't do MAX (I think) because i want to repeat this to create a "Top 10 values" list.  So using LARGE with 2-10 as well.

Comment: @Teach42 That's why I said _if_. I gave you some options, because I have limited knowledge on what you have and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Trying to get the other two working right, having some issues and had to shelve it for some meetings.  Just responding specifically to the MAX one.  But appreciate it, and following up.

Comment: @Teach42 Ah, well that's okay. Just remember that you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter after inserting the formula in the cell(s). And you sure can use `LARGE( ... , 2)` for the next line, then increase that number until you get the top 10.

Comment: @Jerry - You can get problems here with duplicates - if the largest 2 non SKIPME values are equal, for example, LARGE 1 and LARGE 2 will both return the same value and then so will the INDEX formula - also its possible to return values from SKIPME rows if those col D values are duplicates of non SKIPME rows - see my answer to avoid problems with duplicates

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid problems with duplicate values in column D you can use this setup:

In `F2` down to `F11` list the values 1 to 11

In `G2` use this formula confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down to get the associated values from column D

`=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(B$2:B$100<>"SKIPME",IF(D$2:D$100<>"",D$2:D$100)),F2),"")`

then to get the column C items for the top 10 values use this formula in `H2` confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

`=IF(G2="","",INDEX(C$2:C$100,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$100<>"SKIPME",IF(D$2:D$100=G2,ROW(D$2:D$100)-ROW(D$2)+1)),COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2))))`

If there are  fewer than 10 qualifying values you get blanks - see example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xaqtisfeq1ynjj/top10.xlsx)